# Folder Explorer is Not Work well in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub ButtonPath_Click()
    Cells(1, 32).Value = FolderExplorer()
End Sub
```

Above is my UserForm's Code.
Below Code is My Module's FolderExplorer() Function.

```
'//Source : http://software-solutions-online.com/vba-folder-dialog/ , edited by me.
Public Function FolderExplorer()
    Dim intResult As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).ButtonName _
    = "Select Path"
    'the dialog is displayed to the user
    intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
    'checks if user has cancled the dialog.
    If intResult <> 0 Then
        'dispaly message box
        'Call MsgBox(Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker _
        ).SelectedItems(1), _
        vbInformation, "Selected Folder")
        FolderExplorer() = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End Function
```

It seemed working well at first. When I press the button in userform, FolderExplorer Pops up. but when I select the folder path, the Folder Explorer pops up again, and when I select the folder path, the Folder Explorer pops up again.... eternally.

I have no loop in my code. How Can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: Using `FolderExplorer() = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)` you are calling `FolderExplorer()` recursively. So of course you have a loop. Try `FolderExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `FolderExplorer()` recursively in `FolderExplorer() = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)`.

You should use `FolderExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)` to return the value.

Below is a simplified version of your code.

```
Public Function FolderExplorer()
    Dim intResult As Integer
    Dim strPath As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .ButtonName = "Select Path"
        intResult = .Show
        If intResult <> 0 Then
            FolderExplorer = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```